# Connect PHP and Derby Database

Tags: php, derby

Currently I am working with PHP and need to know, if it is possible to connect PHP and Derby database. If yes, anyone can tell me about how to do it? Thanks in advance.

NB: I have read an article about IBM tool, which can be used for connecting both of them. But currently the tools is not downloadable.

Comment: This __old__ [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409casey/) shows you it can be done with OBDC.

Comment: PHP The instructions in this technical article were tested with PHP version 4.3.29 and 5.0.2; version 4.3.29 (!!!) is recommended.

Comment: [Download link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256235) and [Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php)